# Extra noise in speakers when all media applications are closed

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I use Ubuntu 12.04 system on my laptop and have the following problem.

I plugged sound speaker and now I have some extra noise... The most wondering thing is that this extra noise appear only if I don't launch any application.

For instance if I run amarok, vlc or what ever to play music or movie I have high quality clear sound. But when I close that application in a few seconds I get extra noise again.

I didn't have this problem before.

Can somebody help me what is going wrong?

Comment: What kind of noise do you hear? Do you set the volume in Ubuntu or on your speakers?

Comment: Simple white noise. Actually this kind noise I can hear when I unplug my speakers... There is no any noise from laptop speakers. But it looks like when some application are closed some drivers or daemons "switch off" the laptop sound input and noise appear like when speakers are plugged off at all.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your speakers.

If your speakers have a volume control, set the volume to max in Ubuntu and all applications and use only the control of your speakers to adjust volume. This increases the signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: I have this problem with this speakers only with this laptop. I tried to plug speakers to my desktop computer and everything is ok. No noise, just fun.

Comment: The speakers shouldn't even make noise when they're unplugged. Notebook hardware, including soundcards, usually switch off or go to sleep mode when they're unused to save power.